# Why my processes are connecting to 3rd party software website

Tags: security, firewall, process, anti-virus, task-manager

After installing the process hacker I noticed that in-network section most of the processes is connecting to a 3rd party software called "**partitionwizard**" both of the local and remote address are same and my antivirus isn't detecting any virus too[here is the image of process hacker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvJCU.png)
.What kind of virus is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local address *always* has to be a local address – as in an address that's literally assigned to a network adapter on *this* computer. So if a strange domain name shows up as a "local address", that just means one of your own IP addresses is resolving to that strange domain name.

If you use `netstat` or disable the "Resolve network addresses" option in Process Hacker, it's almost guaranteed to show that the actual address is `127.0.0.1` or `::1`.

(Note also that the connections that you see are very often *in pairs* – you see one from port A to B, and another from port B to A. This strongly implies it's a loopback connection and they're actually just two ends of the same connection.)

Most likely, you (or some "ad blocking" software) have put a ton of `127.0.0.1 partitionwizard.com` entries to the /etc/hosts file (well, C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts), where they deliberately have priority over DNS lookups. However, entries there work *both* ways – the file doesn't only translate names to addresses, but also addresses to names. When the system is asked to translate 127.0.0.1 to a name, it'll use whatever domain it finds in the 'hosts' entries.

(For that reason, I would recommend manually adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost` at the very top of the 'hosts' file. Normally Windows doesn't need those entries, but when you have custom ones, you have to add localhost as well.)

So those are loopback connections. As to *why* those loopback connections are made – I'm pretty sure it has to do with your antivirus software (this avp.exe, which is again very noticeably one of the endpoints for each connection) performing "web scanning", i.e. it tries to intercept every single HTTP and HTTPS connection that programs make.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, So that means that the computer is just generating a false domain name in the taskbar and I just have to edit the host file . I almost blocked 127.0.0.1 from the firewall as I don't know much about the networking anyway thanks for the detailed explanation really appreciate it .

Comment: Yeah, don't block 127.0.0.1...